# count matches between two rows of dataframe R

Tags: r, compare, rows

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
          LA          LE         LI        LO          LU 
A          1          0          0          0          0 
B          0          0          1          1          1 
C          0          0          0          0          0
D          1          0          0          0          0
E          1          0          1          1          0
```

and I want to count how many values match between two rows, but not counting equal 0s as a match, only equal 1s. for example AxE = 1, BxE = 2 , but in a way that i will get those values for every combination of 2 rows. im using

```
df = read.table('rmatr.txt', header = TRUE, sep = "\t", row.names = 1)
```

to read my file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try `combn` like below

```
cbind(
  data.frame(t(combn(row.names(df), 2))),
  cnt = combn(asplit(df, 1), 2, FUN = function(x) sum(do.call("*", x)))
)
```

which gives

```
   X1 X2 cnt
1   A  B   0
2   A  C   0
3   A  D   1
4   A  E   1
5   B  C   0
6   B  D   0
7   B  E   2
8   C  D   0
9   C  E   0
10  D  E   1
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(LA = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), LE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), LI = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), LO = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L
), LU = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E"))
```

Comment: hey! i also tried your answer, it worked and it did run faster than the first one, that is still running. thank you!

Comment: Hey @ThomasIsCoding, do you mind explaining how the "sum(do.call("*", x) " is doing this matching? Im confused to why this doesnt return only the sum of the values of the rows.

Comment: @ubuntunoob `x` here is a list containing two rows from `df`. When we do `do.call("*",x)`, we are actually running `x[[1]]*x[[2]]`, which is an element-wise product of rows. Since you have only binary values for rows, the product gives `1`s only if the corresponding positions are both `1`s. Then, we run `sum` to count how many `1`s , which represents the number of common `1`s.

Comment: got it! thank you! so if I want to divide this value by the actual sum of the rows in 'x', can i just add "/(do.call("+",x)" after the "sum(do.call("*", x) " ?

Comment: @ubuntunoob Yes, you got it

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp=do.call(cbind,
  sapply(1:(nrow(df)-1),function(i){
    sapply((i+1):nrow(df),function(j){
      c(i,j,sum(df[i,]==1 & df[j,]==1))
    })
  })
)

data.frame(
  "Row1"=rownames(df)[tmp[1,]],
  "Row2"=rownames(df)[tmp[2,]],
  "cnt"=tmp[3,]
)

   Row1 Row2 cnt
1     A    B   0
2     A    C   0
3     A    D   1
4     A    E   1
5     B    C   0
6     B    D   0
7     B    E   2
8     C    D   0
9     C    E   0
10    D    E   1
```

Comment: hey, thank you for your answer! the only problem is that it is also counting the 0s as a match, when Im only trying to count the 1s as a match.. edit: thank you !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @ubuntunoob That wasn't clear to me from the question, I updated.

Comment: ill edit the question to make it more clear, even though you already answered. thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

We could also use `crossprod` from `base R`

```
out <- as.data.frame.table(tcrossprod(as.matrix(df)))
out[1:2] <- t(apply(out[1:2], 1, sort))
subset(out, Var1 != Var2 & !duplicated(out[1:2]))
#    Var1 Var2 Freq
#2     A    B    0
#3     A    C    0
#4     A    D    1
#5     A    E    1
#8     B    C    0
#9     B    D    0
#10    B    E    2
#14    C    D    0
#15    C    E    0
#20    D    E    1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(LA = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), LE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), LI = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), LO = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L
), LU = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E"))
```